# Create sub schema/folder in Hive is possible?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is it possible to create sub schema in Hive to have:

```
db_name.sub_schema.table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible Hive. In hive the database and schema are essentially the same. From the Hive documentation

> The uses of SCHEMA and DATABASE are interchangeable – they mean the
>   same thing. CREATE DATABASE was added in Hive 0.6 (HIVE-675).  The
>   WITH DBPROPERTIES clause was added in Hive 0.7 (HIVE-1836).